# Updating a Haystack search index with Django + Celery

Tags: python, django, indexing, celery, django-haystack

In my Django project I am using Celery. I switched over a command from crontab to be a periodic task and it works well but it is just calling a method on a model. Is it possible to update my Haystack index from a periodic task as well? Has anyone done this?

```
/manage.py update_index
```

That's the command to update the index from the Haystack documentation but I'm not sure how to call that from a task.

Comment: management commands should optimally just be a thin wrapper around a public API, but sadly it doesn't seem to be the case here; https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py

Comment: as a hack you can use django.core.management.call_command("update_index"), but I would rather copy+paste the code linked above to work independently

Comment: @asksol, Thanks for the reply. Why is call_command considered a hack? It seems simpler to do that the copy paste that whole command.

Comment: Ah, not the whole command. Just the part that is actually doing the index, without the Django command stuff.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

the easiest way to do this would probably be to run the management command directly from python and run it in your task

```
from haystack.management.commands import update_index
update_index.Command().handle()
```

Comment: this worked. Could you explain why this is better than using django.core.management.call_command("update_index") ?

Comment: You're right, that should work just as well, I didn't know about that function :)

Comment: Make sure to `import app.search_indexes` somewhere or it won't work I've found.  The models must be registered or they will be skipped.

Comment: This no longer works on the 2.0.0 beta.  Returns this "ImproperlyConfigured: The key 'None' isn't an available connection."

Comment: You can pass command parameters like so: `update_index.Command().handle(age=1)`

Comment: django.core.management.call_command("update_index") throws an IO error for me in prod. However, this command works perfectly!

Comment: @Neil What does it mean age=1 - is that 1 day or hour? How to pass date from ?

Comment: my rebuild index will ask yes or no question while running in the terminal

Answer (score 12):

As for version 2.0.0 beta of haystack, this code should work:

```
from haystack.management.commands import update_index
update_index.Command().handle(using='default')
```

Comment: There you can also use 'remove' option to remove non-existing entries.   `update_index.Command().handle(using='default',remove=True)`

Comment: As of haystack 2.1.0, `using` accepts list of backends. So it should be `handle(using=['default'])`

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/django-haystack/celery-haystack

I find this package to be a great, easy plug-in app to provide haystack indexing via celery. I used it in a few projects.

Answer (score 7):

Also, since version 2 of the haystack you can call rebuild index from python as

```
from haystack.management.commands import update_index, rebuild_index
rebuild_index.Command().handle(interactive=False)
```

Where the "**interactive**" would prevent haystack asking question if you really want to rebuild index. This is equivalent to --no-input command line option.

If you use xapian as FTS backend please remember that multithreaded updates to index would result in DB Write Lock. So, the solution with celery-haystack package does attempt to spread index update into multiple workers (multiple thread) resulting in the lock with xapian.