# Options for running manage.py actions within a django app

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

Redited for clarification

Hello I have a django app using haystack and a solr backend to power searches (works well)

My task is as below 
1. User uploads a set of concepts which are saved in a django table
2. This data should be made searchable, it cannot work unless you rebuild the index 
3. In cases of production environment where there are several users , it is impractical to keep checking if there is new data by users , and index this manually using the command manage.py rebuild_index 
4. Are there wasy to automate the manage.py tasks in your django app.

Thanks

Comment: "... dynamic addition of data to the django data model ..." Oh boy...

Comment: Have you looked at celery-haystack? It allows you to utilize Celery for automatically updating and deleting objects in a Haystack search index.

Comment: There is no case where you want to dynamically expand your django data model on the fly. Please edit your question and explain the bigger picture - you might be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @SunnySydeUp +1 for your comment , pointed me in the right direction and is easy to do

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment section i refined my search and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358771/updating-a-haystack-search-index-with-django-celery) , which had the answer i was looking for

Another option is [django-celery](http://celery-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

In summary

```
from haystack.management.commands import update_index
    update_index.Command().handle()
```